# String formatting python KeyError

Tags: python, string, kivy

What is the function of the `list` string in the code below:

```
cities = ['{} ({})'.format(d['name'],d['sys']['country']) for d in data['list']]
```

i am asking because in the method `found_location_name` it works

```
def found_location_name(self, request, data):
    data = json.loads(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data, dict) else data
    cities = ['{} ({})'.format(d['name'],d['sys']['country']) for d in data['list']]
    self.search_results.item_strings = cities
```

while here i get KeyError:

```
def found_location_coordinates(self,request_coordinates,data_coordinates):
    data_coordinates = json.loads(data_coordinates.decode()) if not isinstance(data_coordinates, dict) else data_coordinates 
    cities_coordinates = ['{} ({})'.format(d['name'],d['sys']['country']) for d in data_coordinates['list']]
    self.search_results.item_strings = cities_coordinates


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
 WeatherApp().run()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/kivy/app.py", line 792, in run
 runTouchApp()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/kivy/base.py", line 481, in runTouchApp
 EventLoop.window.mainloop()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 381, in mainloop
 self._mainloop()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/kivy/core/window/window_pygame.py", line 287, in _mainloop
 EventLoop.idle()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/kivy/base.py", line 321, in idle
 Clock.tick()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/kivy/clock.py", line 422, in tick
 self._process_events()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/kivy/clock.py", line 537, in _process_events
 if event.tick(self._last_tick) is False:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/kivy/clock.py", line 309, in tick
 ret = callback(self._dt)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/kivy/network/urlrequest.py", line 376, in _dispatch_result
 func(self, data)
File "main.py", line 26, in found_location_coordinates
 cities_coordinates = ['{} ({})'.format(d['name'],d['sys']['country']) for d in data_coordinates['list']]
KeyError: 'list'
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data['list']` means that `data` is a dictionary and you want the value of the `list` key. So, `data` may look like so:

```
data = {
    'list': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Then,

```
>>> data['list']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now, if you try to access a key that doesn't exist, a `KeyError` will be raised:

```
>>> data['qwerty']
<omitted traceback>
KeyError: 'qwerty'
```

So, the `data_coordinates` dictionary does not have a `list` key. If the `data_coordinates` may sometimes have a `list` key and sometimes not, you can use [get()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method that returns `None` or a specified default value if the key doesn't exist:

```
>>> data.get('qwerty')
None
>>> data.get('qwerty', 'default value')
'default value'
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see the content of `data` after the `data = json.loads(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data, dict) else data` line.

Comment: You were right, the data dict indeed has a list argument that contains the dict that i need to use and for some reason the data_coordinates dict contains the actual dict instead of having the list argument.